# session rails 4.1.8 always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a problem with session 
when I checking login successfully on my controller:

```
session[:username]||=[]
session[:username]<< params[:username]
```

and on my view:

```
<% if session[:username]==nil %>
    session nil
<% else %>
    session not nil
<% end %>
```

What always the it returns `session nil`?

Comment: My guess would be that your params[:username] is nil and your setting it that way without knowing it. Otherwise, your not showing enough code to be able to determine more.

Comment: as per code exposed so far `session[:username]` will never be nil, as it will at least be an empty array, you are indeed missing something, some other code might be you are missing, is this across redirection? did you see the session id same across?

Comment: Are you calling `reset_session`, you can ensure your session persist by checking session id is same `puts request.session_options[:id]`

Answer (score 1):

This issue was creating for CSRF verification issue.

Place this code into you application controller. I hope this will solve your issue.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```